Ignite cache is closed and destroyed but still being accessed
We are using Ignite Cache in distributed mode and once the use of cache is over we are calling cache.close() followed by cache.detroy() to make sure that the cache is completed destroyed and removed from the system.
But we are getting "Cache has been closed" exception from Ignite after the cache has been closed and destroyed.
If we remove the close call and only call destroy this scenario never occurs and we never get this error.
I am not sure whats happening and why is cache not getting destroyed.

Calling close on a cache removes the local reference to the cache. It does not affect the tables on the server nodes. Doing anything with the cache object after close doesn't make sense.
Instead, call destroy on your cache object before closing it.
